# Validating Sender Addresses in Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

My app needs to send emails from several addresses: noreply@, accounts@ and support@, for instance. Now I'm setting up country-specific domains.

To send emails from Appengine, the sender address has to be a registered admin. To become an admin, you need to have a Google Apps account. But it appears you can't use aliases ("nicknames") - when you click the invite link, you have to log in, which you can't do as an alias. I think this also means I can't set up the country-specific domains as alias domains in Google Apps.

I'm not a cheapskate, but paying $50 per account (three accounts times five domains - $2,250) per year purely to validate the sender addresses is a bit rich. Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's how it currently works.
From what I understand GAE team is working on alternate solutions and while they figure out something they offer [an AppEngine credit](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1lSDA5Jol0Bosaop3RKZ9YqlSyzVLsCtAv8gYupBheR4/viewform).
But that only works once per App.

We handle this by using an external service (SendGrid, that introduced a [pay-as-you-go](http://sendgrid.com/pricing/lite_plan) offer with the same pricing as AppEngine). However if you want full DKIM or other features it becomes much more expensive.

Comment: Google recommend using SendGrid: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sendgrid